# Is it idiomatic to say "he wakes up early always" or "he wakes up always early"?

Tags: adverbs, word-order

I guess these 3 sentences are all idiomatic.

1. He **always** wakes up early
2. He **usually** wakes up early
3. He wakes up early **usually**

However, I am not so sure if these 2 sentences are idiomatic

1. he wakes up early **always**
2. he wakes up **always** early

In addition, These 3 sentences confuses me much more.

1. "She slowly began to recover." as you can
   see, the adverb "slowly" **usually** comes next to
   before the main verb "began"
2. "She slowly began to recover." as you can
   see, the adverb "slowly" comes **usually** next to
   before the main verb "began"
3. "She slowly began to recover." as you can
   see, the adverb "slowly" comes next to
   **usually** before the main verb "began"

The most important thing is, I just don't know the grammar standard for this kind of cases. Could someone give a link or some keywords?

This [post](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Order-of-Adverbs.htm) gives this order (also known as "Royal Order of Adverbs")

1. Manner
2. Place
3. Frequency
4. Time
5. Purpose

This [video](https://youtu.be/hU3ye0R0cnw?t=95) gives a different one

[image]

Which one should I choose?

I guess the order in that video is incorrect as comments below the video pointed out, though I did find a solid reference for the Royal Order of Adverbs.

Comment: _"She slowly began to recover." as you can see, the adverb "slowly" usually comes next to before the main verb "began."_ Where are these examples from - did you make them?

Comment: @Jan a video about [Position of Adverbs](https://youtu.be/V9OWrWr4fmA?t=165)

Comment: The 1) is OK: She slowly began to recover." as you can see, the adverb "slowly" usually comes before the main verb "began." (so "_usually comes_" = usually before a verb). You don't say "next to before" though. The 2) and 3) are not OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unusual and odd to use the adverbs "usually" or "always" at the end of the sentence.

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/usually):

> The adverb usually refers to what typically or normally happens. We
>   use it mostly in mid position, between the subject and the main verb,
>   or after the modal verb or first auxiliary verb, or after be as a main
>   verb:
>
> - Children usually enjoy visits to the zoo.
> - I usually get up around eight o’clock.
> - You can usually buy tickets for rock concerts on the Internet.
> - Are you usually in your office on Thursdays?

The same rule applies for "[always](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/always)."

Note, that even if "usually and "always" are adverbs, the rules about their position are not necessary the same as for other adverbs (early, slowly...).

Additionally, it sounds odd to use "usually" or "always" in a row with another adverb ending with -ly, like: "He wakes up early usually." It's better to say: "He usually wakes up early."