# Does "I play football at the park near my house every Tuesday evening." sound natural?

Tags: grammar

The answer to this post ([Is it idiomatic to say "he wakes up early always" or "he wakes up always early"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/238415/109190)) says

> It is unusual and odd to use the adverbs "usually" or "always" at the end of the sentence.

I agree with that.

Besides, Cambridge [dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/usually) gives this grammar rule

> The adverb usually refers to what typically or normally happens. We use it mostly in mid position, between the subject and the main verb, or after the modal verb or first auxiliary verb, or after be as a main verb:

I guess the rule above is also applicable to other adverbs of frequency.

> I play football every Tuesday evening at the park near my house."

I am curious that, does putting the adverbs of frequency at the end of the sentence like the following also natural?

> I play football at the park near my house **every Tuesday evening**.

Comment: I don't get this question. You've cited Cambridge Dictionary quite correctly telling you that we ***usually*** use adverbs like "usually" in "mid position". That's what native speakers do, presumably *because* they find this "natural". Then you ask us why you as a ***non*** native speaker think it would ***also*** seem natural to put the highlighted word at the ***end*** of my second sentence in this comment. I have no idea why you would think that, but obviously most native speakers don't.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica I think they're saying "I play football at the park near my house **every Tuesday evening**." sounds natural.

Comment: @CJDennis That's exactly what I mean. Thank you so much!

Comment: oic. Well your example already includes 3 consecutive adverbial elements *(**every Tuesday evening, at the park, near my house**)*, but there's no "syntactic rule" in English governing which ***order*** those elements occur in. Nor is there any limit on the ***number*** of such "chained adverbial elements", so if I wanted to include yet another (for example, ***in summer***), I could validly put that before or after the existing text (as a ***sentence*** adverb), OR immediately before ANY ONE OF the existing three. There is no concept of a "Royal Order of Adverbial Clauses" in English.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica what does oic stand for?

Comment: "Eye dialect" - ***Oh, I see**!*

Comment: We *are* on the Internet here. With most web browsers it would surly be quicker for you to highlight the first two words of my previous comment, right-click, and ***Search Google for "Eye dialect"***, rather than type a whole comment asking *me!* Whatever - it's just a "facetious" term meaning *totally non-standard spelling that **sounds** like the intended utterance, but **looks** (to the eye) like something completely different*.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica Thank you so much. Do you agree that the last example is also natural, which puts adverbial phrase of frequency at the end of the sentence?

Comment: I don't think there's any point in me either agreeing or disagreeing with such a suggestion. *There is no generic principle* involved here that would make it meaningful to single out "adverbial phrase **of frequency**" as somehow different to any other adverbial elements, making them either more or less likely to be used in any particular position within an utterance (that possibly contains an open-ended number of ***other*** adverbial elements).

Comment: The basic rule in English that modifiers should be adjacent to what is modified is slightly altered for adverbial phrases, which may be, and frequently are, the first or last elements in a sentence. FF and I seem to agree on this. We seem to agree as well that there is no rule specifying whether spatial adverbial phrases  precede or follow temporal ones. In this example, however, we have **two** spatial phrases and one temporal one. It would not be natural to insert "every Tuesday night" between "at the park" and "near my home." Adverbial phrases are not lawless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is perfectly natural to put "every Tuesday night" at the end of your example. Yes, usually adverbs are placed close to the adjective or verb that they are modifying. But "every Tuesday night" is an adverbial **phrase** rather than a simple adverb and those frequently come after the direct object or before the subject.

> Every Tuesday night, we play football

and

> We play football every Tuesday night

are both quite natural.